# joomla 3.0 tiny mce editor issue

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 3.0. While saving any article escape sequences are inserted into the text. Eg:

```
<div class="txt">Hello</div>
```

This line turns to

```
<div class=\"txt\">Hello</div>
```

I dont know how to get rid of these escape sequences. Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Joomla 3 you need to have magic quotes disabled. You might need to ask your host how to do that, the procedures differ host to host, but in the end you need to modify or add a php.ini file somewhere.

Comment: Well unfortunately i dont have access to hosting. Is there any other solution from File editing or administrator.

Comment: Solved from here http://entertainmentworkshops.blogspot.com/2012/10/joomla-installation-joomla-30-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I looked thru forum.joomla.com for information on getting rid of magic quotes for Joomla 3, and I tried all the advice in that forum, all with no luck. But I got a solution immediately when I logged a ticket with my hosting provider (ventraip.com.au). Their advice was to use their PHP.INI customiser facility. So in the end the solution was immediate, but that was after wasting a few hours manually modifying php.ini and .htaccess as was suggested in the Joomla forum.

So in summary, I'm of the same opinion as Elin. Contact your hosting provider.